# What type of function should I apply to this data?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have some target data (blue) and I am using an alternative method to come up with an attempt (orange). What type of math function should I apply to the orange attempts to match them up with the blue targets? Keep in mind the axis' are not to scale.
[image: data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my eye, a contraction around the point $(250,550)$ will come close.  Take your attempt, find the distance to $(250,550)$, multiply by some factor a little less than $1$, and go in the same direction that amount.